# Linking an assembler program: error "undefined reference to `printf'"

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit, debian-based

I'm trying to compile this [x86 assembly code](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex_yasm/blob/master/3_basic_yasm/4_exercises/1_read_code/0_strange_calc.asm) on x64 Debian :

```
BITS 32

%include    'training.s' 

global main
extern  exit    

; ===============================================
section .text

main:
    ; The program begins here:

    call    read_hex    
    mov     edx,eax
    call    read_hex    
    add     eax,edx
    add     eax,eax
    inc     eax         

    call    print_eax   

    ; Exit the process:
    push    0
    call    exit
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
~$nasm -f elf -g 0_strange_calc.asm && ld -o 0_strange_calc 0_strange_calc.o
    ld: i386 architecture of input file `0_strange_calc.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
    ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:25: undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:35: undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:45: undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:56: undefined reference to `read'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:77: undefined reference to `scanf'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:97: undefined reference to `scanf'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:108: undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:129: undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.o:training.s:137: undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.o:0_strange_calc.asm:50: undefined reference to `exit'




 ~$ yasm -f elf64 0_strange_calc.asm
    ~$ gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc 0_strange_calc.o -o 0_strange_calc
    /usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `0_strange_calc.o' is incompatible with i386 output
    /usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000080480c0
    0_strange_calc.o: In function `no symbol':
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `read'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `scanf'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `scanf'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `printf'
    0_strange_calc.o: In function `main':
    0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `exit'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my dump of 0_strange_calc.o:

```
~$ objdump -M intel -d 0_strange_calc.o

0_strange_calc.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main-0xc2>:
   0:   60                      (bad)  
   1:   50                      push   rax
   2:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
   7:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   c <main-0xb6>
   c:   83 c4 08                add    esp,0x8
   f:   61                      (bad)  
  10:   c3                      ret    
  11:   60                      (bad)  
  12:   50                      push   rax
  13:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  18:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1d <main-0xa5>
  1d:   83 c4 08                add    esp,0x8
  20:   61                      (bad)  
  21:   c3                      ret    
  22:   60                      (bad)  
  23:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  28:   50                      push   rax
  29:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   2e <main-0x94>
  2e:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
  31:   61                      (bad)  
  32:   c3                      ret    
  33:   60                      (bad)  
  34:   51                      push   rcx
  35:   57                      push   rdi
  36:   6a 00                   push   0x0
  38:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   3d <main-0x85>
  3d:   83 c4 0c                add    esp,0xc
  40:   31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
  42:   c6 04 07 00             mov    BYTE PTR [rdi+rax*1],0x0
  46:   61                      (bad)  
  47:   c3                      ret    
  48:   55                      push   rbp
  49:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  4b:   83 ec 04                sub    esp,0x4
  4e:   53                      push   rbx
  4f:   51                      push   rcx
  50:   52                      push   rdx
  51:   8d 5d fc                lea    ebx,[rbp-0x4]
  54:   53                      push   rbx
  55:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  5a:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   5f <main-0x63>
  5f:   83 c4 08                add    esp,0x8
  62:   8b 03                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbx]
  64:   5a                      pop    rdx
  65:   59                      pop    rcx
  66:   5b                      pop    rbx
  67:   c9                      leave  
  68:   c3                      ret    
  69:   55                      push   rbp
  6a:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  6c:   83 ec 04                sub    esp,0x4
  6f:   8d 5d fc                lea    ebx,[rbp-0x4]
  72:   60                      (bad)  
  73:   53                      push   rbx
  74:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  79:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   7e <main-0x44>
  7e:   83 c4 08                add    esp,0x8
  81:   61                      (bad)  
  82:   8b 03                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbx]
  84:   c9                      leave  
  85:   c3                      ret    
  86:   60                      (bad)  
  87:   56                      push   rsi
  88:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   8d <main-0x35>
  8d:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
  90:   61                      (bad)  
  91:   c3                      ret    
  92:   60                      (bad)  
  93:   b9 20 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0x20
  98:   d1 c0                   rol    eax,1
  9a:   89 c2                   mov    edx,eax
  9c:   83 e2 01                and    edx,0x1
  9f:   51                      push   rcx
  a0:   50                      push   rax
  a1:   52                      push   rdx
  a2:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  a7:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   ac <main-0x16>
  ac:   83 c4 08                add    esp,0x8
  af:   58                      pop    rax
  b0:   59                      pop    rcx
  b1:   e2 e5                   loop   98 <main-0x2a>
  b3:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  b8:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   bd <main-0x5>
  bd:   83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
  c0:   61                      (bad)  
  c1:   c3                      ret    

00000000000000c2 <main>:
  c2:   e8 81 ff ff ff          call   48 <main-0x7a>
  c7:   89 c2                   mov    edx,eax
  c9:   e8 7a ff ff ff          call   48 <main-0x7a>
  ce:   01 d0                   add    eax,edx
  d0:   01 c0                   add    eax,eax
  d2:   40 e8 28 ff ff ff       rex call 0 <main-0xc2>
  d8:   6a 00                   push   0x0
  da:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   df <main+0x1d>
```

It seems to have been converted successfully in x64 asm, other simple code I had compiled and linked without problems. What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear: `i386 architecture is incompatible with i386:x86-64`.

Comment: It also looks like it wants your entry point to be named "start" rather than "main"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a couple of options

- Use *LD* to link to a final executable
- Use *GCC* to link to a final executable

---

## Using LD Method

Your command lines use *LD*, unfortunately that presents a number of problems. The first:

> ld: i386 architecture of input file `0_strange_calc.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-6

You are on 64-bit Debian, trying to produce a 32-bit executable. `-f elf` on the *NASM* command line generates 32-bit ELF (`-f elf64` generate 64 bit objects). Your *LD* command line is by default trying to generate a 64-bit executable thus the error above is given. You can force *LD* to generate a 32-bit executable by adding the `-m elf_i386` option to *LD*'s command line.

> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0

You should tell *LD* that your entry point is *main* . *LD* by default looks for an entry point of *_start*. You can add `-e main` to the *LD* command line to resolve that.

Errors like this suggest you need the *C* library (where *printf* exists):

> 0_strange_calc.asm:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `printf'

Since your code doesn't use *printf* directly I can only assume that is required by the functions in `training.s` . In order to link in the *C* library you will need to add it after the `.o` files in your command line. You can do this with `-lc` on your *LD* command line. You'll also need to tell *LD* specifically what dynamic linker library you will need to use (In this case a 32-bit one). In a Debian environment that will usually look like: `-dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2`

So your *NASM* and *LD* lines should look like this:

```
nasm -f elf -g 0_strange_calc.asm
ld -melf_i386 -e main -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o 0_strange_calc  0_strange_calc.o -lc
```

---

## Using GCC Method

You can simplify linking to the *C* library by using *GCC* to link you your object file to an executable.  To build a 32-bit executable you could use:

```
nasm -f elf -g 0_strange_calc.asm
gcc -m32 0_strange_calc.o -o 0_strange_calc
```

The *C* library and runtime has a *_start* method that does *C* startup initialization and in turn calls a function called *main* which happens to be the function in your assembly file. `-m32` tells *GCC* you are also linking to a 32-bit executable.

---

## Special Considerations

You may also need to to install the *Multlilib* versions of gcc (and g++ if you want to) so that you can properly build and run 32-bit applications on 64-bit Debian using the appropriate *C* libraries. That can be done with this command line:

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

On Ubuntu based systems you'd need to use:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

Comment: It seems to compile, but it doesn't generate any output file. I'm using this commands: ` $ nasm -f elf -g 0_strange_calc.asm `
` ~$ ld -melf_i386 -e main -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2  -o strange_calc  0_strange_calc.o -lc`

Comment: @Kaka The original command line I gave (I fixed it already) output to a file called `strange_calc` (not `0_strange_calc`). That was an error on my part. Just change it to `ld -melf_i386 -e main -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o 0_strange_calc 0_strange_calc.o -lc` (The output file was only thing that was wrong)

Comment: Yes, it generated a file called "strange_calc". Now I manage to run it. The app doesn't seem to give any output, but I suppose this is the expected result. Thank you

Comment: If it isn't printing probably a problem with your code. I don't know how `print_eax`  works since it isn't part of the code given. But if you are linking and get an exectuable, printing being incorrect would likely be better asked in another question if you can't resolve it.

Comment: I just needed to input two numbers. Works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the problem is not the `asm` code but a missing imported function. If you read 
[training.s](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex_yasm/blob/d172b7d0cf72296cd4503c1607c1413ecfb6cf03/include/training.s) you will see the definition of `printeax` and other methods as well.  Moreover you will see that some of those method use `external function` like `printf` which is of course not `asm` function but some imported language lib

```
BITS 32
extern printf
extern exit
extern scanf
extern read
```

So in order to make it work - i.e to find those external libs ( you have also warning there that you should handle but this is out of this scope). You need to use the linker properly. According to `Frank` at the [nasm board](http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=999.0) you have two options

1. use the `ld` linker but tell it to use `c` lib via `lc` options. i.e: `ld -ld -o 0_strange_calc 0_strange_calc.o -lc`. More info can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)
2. use the `gcc` linker.

P.S
Note that also the code uses `32bit` which on your computer produce a warning as you can use `64 bit` and you use `elf` flag. More on it you can find at the [nasm docs](http://In%20most%20cases,%20you%20should%20not%20need%20to%20use%20BITS%20explicitly.%20The%20aout,%20coff,%20elf,%20macho,%20win32%20and%20win64%20object%20formats,%20which%20are%20designed%20for%20use%20in%2032-bit%20or%2064-bit%20operating%20systems,%20all%20cause%20NASM%20to%20select%2032-bit%20or%2064-bit%20mode,%20respectively,%20by%20default.%20The%20obj%20object%20format%20allows%20you%20to%20specify%20each%20segment%20you%20define%20as%20either%20USE16%20or%20USE32,%20and%20NASM%20will%20set%20its%20operating%20mode%20accordingly,%20so%20the%20use%20of%20the%20BITS%20directive%20is%20once%20again%20unnecessary.)

Comment: I keep getting `cannot find -lc` with `ld`, any idea why? _Is it possible that it has to do something with me using MinGW toolkit?_